# USB Key web server with protected php scripts

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, server, portability

I just started to work for a new customer. He sell access to his Cloud App, written in PHP/MySQL. Recently he got an inquiry from two of his customers asking if he could install the tool locally.

Before doing so, he would like to ask one of his representative to perform a demonstration on site, and asked me if I could create a portable version of the app on USB Drive.

There's no issue with that, except he want the PHP Scripts to be protected/encrypted, so they could not be just copied over.

Do you know how I could manage to do this? Do I have to set up a virtual machine with protected contents? Should I use any existing tool allowing to protect things like that?

Comment: Make it a Client Server Application, 95% of your codes will be on your server, while on USB is client app that will send request to server and receive content in response. PHP is a Server Side Application, keep it simple, keep it on the server.  Write a client app and keep that on USB.

Comment: I didn't made myself clear... This is to deploy in business who don't have reliable internet connection... And THERE IS ... :) So my question stands. I need a portable server for demo purpose... As there's multiple representative, the client fear there's a risk at getting the code stolen... That's why I asked this.